# CKEditor format tags and a custom <small> tag

Tags: ckeditor

Is there a way to add a tag to the format dropdown that would wrap the text in `<small></small>` tags?

Editing **config.js** as follows causes a runtime error:

```
config.format_tags = 'small;p;h1;h2;h3;pre';
```

probably because `<small>` is not block level?

Comment: The idea behind the formats drop-down is that it defines block level formats. For inline ones it's better to use the styles drop-down. And if you want to have block and inline styles in one drop down, then the [styles drop-down](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_styles) is a better choice IMO.

Comment: Thanks, I will investigate the preferred option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason of the runtime error is, that js can not find `CKEDITOR.config.format_small`.

You have to do two things:

1. Search for `CKEDITOR.config.format_h6` in `ckeditor.js` and add `CKEDITOR.config.format_small={element:"small"};`. Then the error is gone, but you can not see the entry yet.
2. open the languagefile you want (e.g. `en.js`) and add `"tag_small":"small text"`.
   now CKEditor supports the `small` tag.

This works for me, I hope it works for you too.

Comment: Thank you for the instructions.  It works. I will accept the answer, but look into the Styles dropdown as well, as @Reinmar suggested.

Comment: I would add that the language files contain nested object.  Find "format":{...} and define your tag in there, for example "format":{"tag_section":"Section"}

Answer (score 1):

If I want to add a custom **section** tag to format tags, this work for me:
1. Go to config.js, add 
config.format_tags = 'h1;h2;h3;h4;h5;h6;**section**'; 
**config.format_section = { element : 'section' };**
2. Then open the languagefile you want (e.g. en.js) -> lang/en.js 
search for "tag_pre":"Formatted", and add **"tag_section":"Section"**.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to wrap text in a certain tag, you can also achieve this with the `Style` dropdown as well.

1. First, configure your editor to allow styles at `/admin/config/content/formats/manage/full_html`. Replace `full_html` with whatever editor version you want to modify
2. Drag the `Styles` button to the active toolbar if it isn't already there
3. Add items to "Styles Dropdown" tab under CKEditor plugin settings

Each option takes the form `css_selector | Human Visible Name` so in your case, you'd add `small.my_element_class | Super Special Small` or something similar.

Instructions abbreviated from this post: https://www.axelerant.com/resources/team-blog/drupal-8-custom-styles-in-ckeditor